# How to create my own Ubuntu package building/hosting like Launchpad PPA?

Tags: ubuntu, hosting, packages, launchpad

Launchpad is great though, but I'd like to know whether I can do it myself, because the network connection to Launchpad.net is too slow from China. (while this is not the only reason)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launchpad is open source.